# Update Android Service TextView from Activity/ Static Method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

**Background**:

I've created a custom service as:

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {
    public static  FloatingViewService self;
     onCreate() { 
       self = this;
       addView(....)
     }

     ... 
     ...
   public void updateText ( String newText) { this.textView.setText(newText) };

 }
```

OnCreate event of this service, it sets a view using WindowManager.addView(...) and also set an instance pointer in self variable for future use.

Now this view is just a textview, that stays on the top of activities, regardless.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to send some data from a static method that runs using ExecutorService instance, which should update textview text.

**How I use this service:**

Inside of an activity, I make a call to a static method that logs some values:

```
public class MyActivity: Activity
{
   public void log() {

       LogUtil.log(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //log api call
               FloatingViewService.self.updateText("New Text");
            }
        }) ;
}
}
```

**Now you can see that I am making a call to an updateText method present in service, from different thread.**

Here is how the LogUtil is:

```
public class LogUtil { 
private static ExecutorService  taskExecutorService = ThreadUtils.createTimedExecutorService(TASK_POOL_SIZE, TASK_POOL_IDLE_ALIVE_SECONDS,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LowPriorityThreadFactory());

  public static log(Runnable runnable) { 

      taskExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ../
                }
            }
        });
```

Now the problem is, it cannot update textview text. I can understand it is due to thread. But I have no clue on how to achieve it - is there any UIthread for service ?

Comment: first: "self" is stupid idea ... seriously use LocalBinder ... second: create Handler in Service constructor .. then use it to post TextView text update ...

Comment: @Selvin it is done to achieve end result. Any coding help ?

Comment: @Selvin I cannot claim to be a champion of all and I don't need your code, however I was wondering with some ref. Yes, I am new with this approach that you have mentioned. I hope it is not a crime. I read through  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample and seems to be overcomplicated with my knowledge. Any thoughts?

Comment: instead creating new Handler you can also use `View.post(Runnable)` in `updateText` like  `this.textView.post(runnable which will do a text change)` ... *and seems to be overcomplicated with my knowledge. Any thoughts?* yeah, one ... then programming itself is overcomplicated ....

Comment: @Selvin Thanks mate for your quick direction. I could managed to get it going however, I am still struggling to use LocalBinder. But the problem is I need service object from log static method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for example .. you shuold be able to pick the necesary parts from it. as Selvin said you have to create an Incoming handler on both sides to send information from one thread to the other...

***Here is my service code***

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;
    import com.pekam.myandroidtheme.*;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.os.Messenger;
    import android.os.RemoteException;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MyService  extends Service {

            private NotificationManager nm;
            private Timer timer = new Timer();
            private int counter = 0, incrementby = 1;
            private static boolean isRunning = false;

            ArrayList<Messenger> mClients = new ArrayList<Messenger>(); // Keeps track of all current registered clients.
            int mValue = 0; // Holds last value set by a client.
            static final int MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT = 1;
            static final int MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT = 2;
            static final int MSG_SET_INT_VALUE = 3;
            static final int MSG_SET_STRING_VALUE = 4;
            final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler()); // Target we publish for clients to send messages to IncomingHandler.


            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                return mMessenger.getBinder();
            }
            class IncomingHandler extends Handler { // Handler of incoming messages from clients.
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT:
                        mClients.add(msg.replyTo);
                        break;
                    case MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT:
                        mClients.remove(msg.replyTo);
                        break;
                    case MSG_SET_INT_VALUE:
                        incrementby = msg.arg1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
            private void sendMessageToUI(int intvaluetosend) {
                for (int i=mClients.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    try {
                        // Send data as an Integer
                        mClients.get(i).send(Message.obtain(null, MSG_SET_INT_VALUE, intvaluetosend, 0));

                        //Send data as a String
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("str1", "ab" + intvaluetosend + "cd");
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_SET_STRING_VALUE);
                        msg.setData(b);
                        mClients.get(i).send(msg);

                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // The client is dead. Remove it from the list; we are going through the list from back to front so this is safe to do inside the loop.
                        mClients.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                Log.i("MyService", "Service Started.");
                showNotification();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){ public void run() {onTimerTick();}}, 0, 100L);
                isRunning = true;
            }
            private void showNotification() {
                nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
                CharSequence text = getText(R.string.service_started);
                // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
                // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TabBarActivity.class), 0);
                // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.service_label), text, contentIntent);
                // Send the notification.
                // We use a layout id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
                nm.notify(R.string.service_started, notification);
            }
            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                Log.i("MyService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
                return START_STICKY; // run until explicitly stopped.
            }

            public static boolean isRunning()
            {
                return isRunning;
            }


            private void onTimerTick() {
                Log.i("TimerTick", "Timer doing work." + counter);
                try {
                    counter += incrementby;
                    sendMessageToUI(counter);

                } catch (Throwable t) { //you should always ultimately catch all exceptions in timer tasks.
                    Log.e("TimerTick", "Timer Tick Failed.", t);            
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                if (timer != null) {timer.cancel();}
                counter=0;
                nm.cancel(R.string.service_started); // Cancel the persistent notification.
                Log.i("MyService", "Service Stopped.");
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
```

***here is my android form app code***

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.pekam.myandroidtheme.*;

public class MyServiceControllerActivity extends Activity {

        Button btnStart, btnStop, btnBind, btnUnbind, btnUpby1, btnUpby10;
        TextView textStatus, textIntValue, textStrValue;
        Messenger mService = null;
        boolean mIsBound;
        final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

        class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case MyService.MSG_SET_INT_VALUE:
                    textIntValue.setText("Int Message: " + msg.arg1);
                    break;
                case MyService.MSG_SET_STRING_VALUE:
                    String str1 = msg.getData().getString("str1");
                    textStrValue.setText("Str Message: " + str1);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        }
        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                mService = new Messenger(service);
                textStatus.setText("Attached.");
                try {
                    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT);
                    msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
                    mService.send(msg);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // In this case the service has crashed before we could even do anything with it
                }
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                // This is called when the connection with the service has been unexpectedly disconnected - process crashed.
                mService = null;
                textStatus.setText("Disconnected.");
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.exampleservice);
            btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
            btnBind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBind);
            btnUnbind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUnbind);
            textStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
            textIntValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textIntValue);
            textStrValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStrValue);
            btnUpby1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpby1);
            btnUpby10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpby10);

            btnStart.setOnClickListener(btnStartListener);
            btnStop.setOnClickListener(btnStopListener);
            btnBind.setOnClickListener(btnBindListener);
            btnUnbind.setOnClickListener(btnUnbindListener);
            btnUpby1.setOnClickListener(btnUpby1Listener);
            btnUpby10.setOnClickListener(btnUpby10Listener);

            restoreMe(savedInstanceState);

            CheckIfServiceIsRunning();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString("textStatus", textStatus.getText().toString());
            outState.putString("textIntValue", textIntValue.getText().toString());
            outState.putString("textStrValue", textStrValue.getText().toString());
        }
        private void restoreMe(Bundle state) {
            if (state!=null) {
                textStatus.setText(state.getString("textStatus"));
                textIntValue.setText(state.getString("textIntValue"));
                textStrValue.setText(state.getString("textStrValue"));
            }
        }
        private void CheckIfServiceIsRunning() {
            //If the service is running when the activity starts, we want to automatically bind to it.
            if (MyService.isRunning()) {
                doBindService();
            }
        }

        private OnClickListener btnStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                startService(new Intent(MyServiceControllerActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        };
        private OnClickListener btnStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                doUnbindService();
                stopService(new Intent(MyServiceControllerActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        };
        private OnClickListener btnBindListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                doBindService();
            }
        };
        private OnClickListener btnUnbindListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                doUnbindService();
            }
        };
        private OnClickListener btnUpby1Listener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                sendMessageToService(1);
            }
        };
        private OnClickListener btnUpby10Listener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                sendMessageToService(10);
            }
        };
        private void sendMessageToService(int intvaluetosend) {
            if (mIsBound) {
                if (mService != null) {
                    try {
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.MSG_SET_INT_VALUE, intvaluetosend, 0);
                        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
                        mService.send(msg);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        void doBindService() {
            bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            mIsBound = true;
            textStatus.setText("Binding.");
        }
        void doUnbindService() {
            if (mIsBound) {
                // If we have received the service, and hence registered with it, then now is the time to unregister.
                if (mService != null) {
                    try {
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT);
                        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
                        mService.send(msg);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // There is nothing special we need to do if the service has crashed.
                    }
                }
                // Detach our existing connection.
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mIsBound = false;
                textStatus.setText("Unbinding.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            try {
                doUnbindService();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TabBarActivity", "Failed to unbind from the service", t);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: well for my purpose it is just right .... there are some extra things implemnted wich you wont need to just have basic functionality..... its a full functionable app that tracks info about state service and clients connected .... you wont need all of this ..... but this is the way it worked for me for my purpose of service controller that interchanges information with the service or exceutes commands within the service

Comment: also it is not what he wants... you are updating the Activity UI ... not Service UI (he is doing Floating view as same as fx in facebook messanger) ... your service doesn't have it ... so, no it is not an answer to his question

Comment: but .... even if ... LocalBinder should be enough ...  `mClients ` could be an array of interface (and activity could just implement it) ... there is no need for Messenger if you are using a Service in the same process as an Activity ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to stay on UIThread to update UI. A solution may be:

- Create a static reference of activity. Remember to set it on resume method of activity and to unset it on pause method.
- On the service side you can invoke a method of activiy to update UI.

Translating those operations in pseudocode. The activity will become :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   public static MainActivity reference;

   ... 

   public onResume() {
       reference=this;
   }

   public onPause() {
       reference=null;
   }

   public void needToUpdateText(final String text)
   {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
          public void run() { 
          Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread with text "+text);
        });
    } 
   }

}
```

And the service class:

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service {

     ... 

   public void updateText ( String newText)
   { 
       if (MainActivity.reference!=null)
       {
         MainActivity.reference.needUpdateText(newText);
       }
 };
```

}

Comment: He don't wana update Activity UI from service ... but Service UI from some kind of UI/Main thread ...

Comment: A service is a component which runs in the background without direct interaction with the user. As the service has no user interface, it is not bound to the lifecycle of an activity. - from (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). Services does background task and activities interacts with UI and user. I suggested to have another approach to the problem.

Comment: And? Did you at least read the question? He added view from service... And yes, it is possible... Fx. https://github.com/alexstyl/FloatingViewService